# Scene components and renderer

Tags: architecture, rendering, scene-graph

I'm currently writing a very small game engine for learning purposes, and hit a block when trying to separate the engine's logic from the "rendering" module.

My current approach is to feed my renderer with a pointer to a "Scene", iterate through its nodes, test them with a static_cast(yeah you read that right) to a "Renderable" object (for example a static mesh class that contains a material and a vertex array) and draw.

I'm aware that this approach is terrible but I can't think of an alternative. At this point I feel like my architecture is complete spaghetti. Any indication would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm aware that this approach is terrible but I can't think of an alternative.

Design-wise, your approach is fine. A rendering interface should know how to consume objects that describe a single (or set of) drawing requests and translate those into state configuration and draw calls for the underlying graphics API. For your renderer, it sounds like your `Renderable` objects are exactly that: a representation of something to draw. So this is fine.

Implementation-wise, however, your approach has some minors flaws.

> My current approach is to feed my renderer with a pointer to a "Scene", iterate through its nodes, test them with a static_cast(yeah you read that right) to a "Renderable" object (for example a static mesh class that contains a material and a vertex array) and draw.

It sounds like you are coupling the renderer to the scene this way (by having the renderer "know about" scene types, such as `Scene` and `Node`; it sounds like `Renderable` is a child of the latter and that the former is a broader type of scene than *just* a rendering one (that is, that you have `Node` types that are not rendering-related).

Furthermore, [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) isn't a good way to "test" nodes. It will always "succeed" in performing a downcast (take a look at point #2 in under the Explanation section in the above link about `static_cast`), but using the resulting `Renderable` may result in a crash because the `Node` really *was not* a `Renderable`. [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) would be the right tool here.

But there's no reason to involve down-casting at all. Rather than give you renderer a `Scene` directly, just change its interface so it gets a set of `Renderable` objects, such as via a `const std::vector<Renderable*>&` parameter. Now the `Renderer` doesn't "know about" the `Scene`.

`Renderable` itself doesn't need to derive from `Node`, it can just be a base class on its own. Now your renderer is decoupled entirely from `Scene` and its related higher-level API.

In the `Scene` itself, store the array of `Renderable` objects for the scene *separately* from the nodes in the scene. You can have nodes in the scene fill this list up with `Renderable` objects they'd like to have drawn as part of the routine processing of your logic update. Then, at the start of rendering for that frame, you just give the renderer the list of `Renderable` objects that the scene has built up for that frame, and let it do its job.

The key idea here is that the "scene" is a high level concept and the renderer is a lower-level one. High level APIs can know about, and use, lower-level ones but such visibility should not go the other way. By enforcing that kind of unidirectional data flow you can keep code less coupled and simpler.